# Can "had to" and "would have to" mean the same thing?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> Mary had to deal with the issue herself.
>
> Mary would have to deal with the issue herself.

Can both sentences mean the same, given the proper context?

Example:

> No one picked up her phone. Mary had to deal with the issue herself.
>
> No one picked up her her phone. Mary would have to deal with the issue herself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they mean pretty much the same in this case.

The first example, "Mary had to", shows the simple past.  If we were telling the story in the present tense, this sentence would be "Mary has to deal with the issue herself".

The second example has the conditional, "Mary would have to".  Here it represents the backshifted future.  If we were telling the story in the present tense, this sentence would be "Mary will have to deal with the issue herself".

If there is a subtle difference, it is that the first example presents her need to do it herself as a fact, whereas the second presents it as a presumption by her or others.  However, in practice, it is perfectly possible for either sentence to be followed by other sentences that contradict it ("Just as she was about to begin, Bob offered to take her place").